# Is Allah a male or a female?

Tags: allah

As Islam says humans should not pray to anybody other than Allah. It condemns worshipping idols. Islam says God is almighty, he has no form. My doubt is when there is no form, how can you define whether he is a male or a female? Can we refer to him as "she"?

NOTE: I have never read Quran, I just got this doubt as a flash in my mind yesterday while I was reading some book. It's just my doubt, if the answer is in the Holy-book, please refer to that, I will read and understand.

Comment: I think this question has little difference from other one. OP asking extra question: "Can we refer to him as "she"?" This is not explained in other question.

Answer (score 3):

Allah has no gender. when we see the word "HE" to mention Him, its just the weakness of language. like there is no word like a Supreme being like Allah, who has no gender. and languages are designed keeping in mind that there are majority of times only 2 genders, male and female.

So Allah is Unique and Free from any form of gender, but as we dont have any special word to address him in human made languages, we use HE for him mostly in Quran

Comment: This could also be used a support for your claim https://islamqa.info/en/98689

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Surah Al-Ikhlas](http://quran.com/112); Allah is not like His creation. So any attribute from His creation can not define Him. Having genitals or eyes or ears is not attribute of Allah.

> Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One,
>
> Allah , the Eternal Refuge.
>
> He neither begets nor is born,
>
> Nor is there to Him any equivalent."

No form means no female also. Referring Allah change in every language. Unfortunately, there is no gender-less refer  in Arabic and English. In quran Allah refer himself with "him". However in Turkish there is no gender in pronouns. So Turkish people call him "O" (he or she).

It's about knowing concept of Allah. If you know Allah has no gender and if you feel better when you call Allah as "She", I think there is no problem. As far as I know, there is no rule about forbidding to call Allah as "She".

Answer (score 1):

"Male" and "female" are used for beings that reproduce by the coming together of two different genders of the same species. The Creator does not reproduce, hence It has no gender.

Having said that, The Creator is a being, that is beyond our understanding and it is unlike any physical or meta-physical shape we can think of. My understanding is that the vision/sight/appearance (or whatever you call it) of The Creator is not provided to us in our mind capacity while we were created, which makes it impossible to think or imagine of It.

Hopefully, we will see It on the judgement day, with bright faces (us).

Answer (score 0):

In arabic language the male tence is used for singular nouns, therefore Allah is referred to as Him because Allah is one.

Comment: How is that would you mind elaborating? (See [answer]).